# jquery: multiple paths in option plugins?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, raty

I'm using a plugin for star ratings: [raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty)

It has a path option where you can set your path to find your star images. I was wondering if jQuery allows multiple paths to be set or does it only work if the plugin has defined the ability?

for instance in the plugin, you'd normally do:

```
  $('.stars').raty
    readOnly: true
    path: '../assets'
```

Can you do something like this:

```
  $('.stars').raty
    readOnly: true
    path: ['../assets', '../../assets']
```

or something? Obviously this array doesn't work. The hack I did was just to change the class, but was curious if its possible to do it without changing class.

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with it. This is part of the design of the plugin, not something jQuery does. So check the raty documentation to see what it allows there. Also, you seem to be missing some parentheses and braces around the options.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, thats what I wanted to hear. No, I'm not missing parentheses. I'm using coffee script

Comment: You should put that in your tag or question text to avoid confusing readers.